# Configuring fixed IP address based on MAC with dnsmasq give duplicate IP error

Tags: linux, dhcp, dnsmasq, ip-address

In order to allow monit to use ping to check whether devices are 'up' I want to have fixed IP addresses. I am using dnsmasq and have a separate file to configure these. e.g.

```
dhcp-host=00:27:02:13:be:6b,SolarEdge,192.168.1.20,3d
```

These devices currently have 'live' leases. When I uncomment the line (such as the above)z dnsmasq refuse to start with this error:

```
Nov 25 10:33:51 iot1 dnsmasq[28239]: duplicate dhcp-host IP address 192.168.1.20 at line 10 of /etc/dnsmasq.d/sethost
Nov 25 10:33:51 iot1 dnsmasq[28239]: FAILED to start up
```

This only started recently but I can't recall any changes I made that might have caused this.

I know my way around dnsmasq generally but am by no means an expert so would appreciate any ideas of how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the line in dnsnasq.conf

```
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d/,*.conf
```

doesn't exclude files like sethost.conf.save which was a backup of the .conf file. Deleting the .save file cured the problem.